# Changing varactor capacitance based on different frequencies

Tags: vco, varactor

I am working on a project that uses a varactor diode in a VCO to output a certain frequency. As I understand it, changing the voltage amplitude changes the capacitance of the varactor diode. The input, however, is supposed to be varying frequencies and not varying amplitudes.

Is there a quick way to change the varactor capacitance based of different frequencies? If not, is there a way to change amplitude based on different frequencies?

Also let me know if my understanding of varactors is lacking and the circuit works with varying frequencies already. It was hard to make a SPICE model of the circuit due to the lack of varactor models, so I simulated the circuit with changing capacitance, which works.

[image: This is what the circuit is based on]

[image: Simulated Spice modle]

The changed values of R, L, and Cs are to suit my purpose.

Comment: A frequency-to-voltage converter?

Comment: "*The input however is supposed to be varying frequencies and not varying amplitudes*" -- if by input you mean the polarization voltage then you're mistaken: the input is DC. So your schematic has the wrong type of source modelled for `Vin`. Also, LTspice has a varicap symbol (`varactor`) and two `.model`s for it: `KV1471` and `MV2201`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am working on a project that uses varactor diode in VCO to output certain frequency.

The VCO frequency depends mostly on the capacitance of C2, C1 and L1, with some influence from C3 and C4, and a smaller influence from the parasitics of Q1 and the other components round it.

> As I understand changing the voltage amplitude changes the capacitance of the varactor diode.

Amplitude of what voltage? Amplitude of the output RF voltage, yes, a little, but that's a second order effect. Amplitude of the tuning voltage V-varicap? Yes, but we don't normally describe a DC voltage as having an 'amplitude'.

I notice you are driving V-varicap from an AC source. If you are expecting this input to frequency modulate the VCO, then the AC modulation source should be in series with a DC bias source. For instance, V-varicap might swing between 1.0 V and 2.0 V, being 1.5 V on average. You could make this with a DC bias of 1.5 V, added to an AC modulation source of 0.5 V peak amplitude.

To first order, the bias component controls the average, or centre, frequency.
The amplitude of the modulation component of V-varicap controls the frequency deviation away from the centre frequency.

As the voltage -> capacitance -> frequency tuning curve of the varactor+VCO is non-linear, then to second order, the amplitude of the modulation voltage does alter the average frequency a little.

> The input however is supposed to be varying frequencies and not varying amplitudes. Is there a quick way to change the varactor capacitance based of different frequencies? If not is there a way to change amplitude based on different frequencies?

I have no idea what this means, or what you are asking.

> Also let me know if my understanding of varactors is lacking and the circuit works with varying frequencies already.

It sounds like your understanding of varactors and oscillators is lacking.

> It was hard to make a spice model of the circuit due to the lack of varactor models so I simulated the circuit with changing capacitance which works.

Modelling a varactor as a constant value capacitor, whose value can be changed as a function of the V-varicap, will give you an excellent first order model.